# Need help for a Python Snake game

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm currently creating a Snake game on Python using the TKinter library.
So right now, I've implemented the movements, the food system, and the score system. I still need some help on how I can make the snake grow when it eats the food.

Comment: lels for reuse notification copyrighting. I think answers should also contain licenses.

Comment: Anything that you post to Stack Overflow will be under the terms of the Creative Commons license. You can find more information by looking at the bottom right of the page and clicking the cc-wiki

Comment: Thanks for the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see the associated code that actually displays the current position of the snake on the screen and remove it after movement, but this is where you can change the size if you make the length of the snake variable and have it drawn and removed in an iterate fashion. When food is eaten, you can simply increase the size of the snake length variable and pause the erasing of the snake movement as it proceeds along its vector until the desired growth has occurred, at which time removal can proceed at the new length rate. Please clarify the part of the code that actually renders the snakes position.

Comment: hi, There's no screen refreshing process. I juste change the coords of the "snake" : game.coords(player, playerX1, playerY1).
I'll try to make a new version with a refresh process, like for the score value

Comment: In this case, each time the food is eaten, increment the size of the length variable of the snake and store the corresponding X and Y coordinates in a location dictionary. During collision testing, iterate through the location dictionary to confirm movement location will not collide with current snake position. During the movement routine, iterate through the location dictionary to increment each piece of the snake rather than just moving the snake as a single variable.